# how to create a virtual glasses try-on with react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a react native app where a user has the ability to try on the frames virtually on his eyes just like lenskart. Is there anything I can get started with?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [viro](https://github.com/viromedia/viro) for Android and IOS.

or

[react-native-arkit](https://github.com/react-native-ar/react-native-arkit) for IOS only.

Here's some tutorials:

[augmented reality react-native](https://medium.com/lightbase/augmented-reality-react-native-6385b6c2fad2)

[Building Cross-Platform AR Apps With React Native](https://arvrjourney.com/building-cross-platform-ar-apps-with-react-native-384d997da56a)